# Assuming independence between 2 samples from the same subject

Tags: deep-learning, classification

I have a question regarding a clinical experiment that I'm handling. I'm using a deep learning framework to classify activity based on some physiological data.

Some of the subjects in the experiment attended multiple experimental sessions. However, these sessions are several months apart. At first, I pooled the data per-subject, regardless of time.

However, some physiological parameters can change over several months, e.g., individuals losing/gaining weight, taking up smoking etc.

Therefore, given the above, how would it be wrong to regard these each session as a separate subject, or should I stick with pooling them per-subject?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give more detail about the goal? If you measure some outcome by subject, it seems to me that a subject-based instance should represent all the sessions with this subject.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Erwan. I'm trying to discern whether a person was resting or performing a certain activity, based on their ECG. I've tried several types of networks, but they all seem to overfit at some point. I expected to see lower classification accuracy in the leave-one-subject-out validation. Yet, I suspect that the large intra-subject variances due to physiological changes over time may mitigate the classification accuracy. In other words - the networks can't distinguish between rest and activity within each subject because each mode differs between sessions.

Comment: Ok I think I see: so the target is something like rest/activity at this particular time, which should be more or less independent whether it's the same/different patient, but the evolution of the intra-patient features across time might invalidate the independence assumption (right?). My first idea would be to do some kind of stratified sampling across time (or number of sessions), in order to compare the performance at different points in time, but for this you need to have enough different patients. This also makes me think of sequential learning: the idea would be that each patient is ...

Comment: ... represented as a sequence across time, and the outcome is another sequence with the target variable. However it's likely that this would require significantly more data, especially if you already have overfitting. In fact my intuition would be to try solve the overfitting first, because it's going to be tricky to obtain anything reliable otherwise. I'm not at all expert with images so I'm not sure what to do about it, the general advice is to reduce the complexity of the model (or increase the data but I assume that this is not possible).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!